# How can i get the total of a column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Alright, I am kind of new to SQL and I have no idea on how I am going to do this. I have tried to google but maybe I'm not sure if I am searching for the right question. So here it is. I have 2 tables in my database. One is called `events` and another one is called `eventtypes`.

My `eventtype` table looks like this..

```
-------------------
eventID | eventName|
   1    | eveA     |  
   2    | eveB     |  
   3    | eveC     |  
___________________
```

and my `events` table, looks like this

```
--------------------------
eventCat |UserRegistered |
   1     | John          |  
   2     | Mac           |  
   3     | Assz          | 
   2     | Ez            |  
   3     | Pz            |  
_________________________
```

(I hope you understand my table.....)

`events.eventCat=eventtype.eventID`

Now, what I am  trying to do is to, calculate the numbers of participants for event 1, 2 and 3 in `events` table and later display the number of users who will be attending appropriately by using the `eventtype` table using php.

Can somebody help me out with this ? Thanks a bunch !

Comment: You mean like select count(*) from eventtype where [condition]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply join and group by to acheive this -

```
SELECT count(UserRegistered),eventName from events join eventtype on
  events.eventCat=eventtype.eventID
     GROUP BY eventCat
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you ! This did the trick. I should start getting familiar with sql more. Thanks again for the quick solution @AfshanShujat

Answer (score 2):

```
create table eventtype
(   eventID int not null,
    eventName varchar(100) not null
);
insert eventtype(eventID,eventName) values
(1,'eveA'),
(2,'eveB'),
(3,'eveC');

create table events
(   eventCat int not null,
    UserRegistered varchar(100) not null
);
insert events(eventCat,UserRegistered) values
(1,'John'),
(2,'Mac'),
(3,'Assz'),
(2,'Ez'),  
(3,'Pz');
```

Query:

```
select e.eventId,count(u.UserRegistered) as theCount 
from eventtype e 
join events u 
on u.eventCat=e.eventId 
group by e.eventId 
order by e.eventId; 
+---------+----------+
| eventId | theCount |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        1 |
|       2 |        2 |
|       3 |        2 |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to provide me with a quick solution ! Well i did not apply this method but i can get a picture of how it is done ! Thanks again @Drew !

Answer (score 1):

The followng query should work.it will select the no of participants based on the event using group by clause

```
 SELECT count(UserRegistered),eventName
 From events,eventype
 WHERE events.eventCat=eventtype.eventID
 GROUP BY eventCat
```

Comment: Thank you, @coder for the quick reply ! I tried your method and it worked too ! Thanks a bunch man :)

Comment: @topacoBoy, glad to help although i answered it first